# Stop printing ppt template final pages

Tags: printing, microsoft-powerpoint

We use powerpoint templates to create our internal and external decks.  When printing the decks I'd like it so that the final 2 pages never print but I want them available to display when presented on a monitor.  Is there a way to have some code on the last 2 pages that don't allow them to print?